# strange error in loops

Tags: python, dictionary

I have dict

```
{
    "count_casinos": 4,
    "casinos": {
        "16": {
            "fields": [
                {"casino_logo": "assets/images/crown.png"},
                {"raiting_casino": "9"},
                {"bonus_code": "AX7772"},
                {"bonus_summa": "200"},
                {"bonus_min_depozit": "1000000"},
                {"bonus_veizdjer": "4"}],
            "title": "Royal casino casino1"},
        "17": {
            "fields": [
                {"casino_logo": "assets/images/crown.png"},
                {"raiting_casino": "8.2"},
                {"bonus_code": "AX777"},
                {"bonus_summa": "200"},
                {"bonus_min_depozit": "1000000"},
                {"bonus_veizdjer": "4"}],
            "title": "Royal casino casino3"},
        "18": {
            "fields": [
                {"casino_logo": "assets/images/crown.png"},
                {"raiting_casino": "9.3"},
                {"bonus_code": "AX7772"},
                {"bonus_summa": "200"},
                {"bonus_min_depozit": "1000000"},
                {"bonus_veizdjer": "4"}],
            "title": "Royal casino casino2"},
        "15": {
            "fields": [
                {"casino_logo": "assets/images/crown.png"},
                {"raiting_casino": "9.9"},
                {"bonus_code": "AX777"},
                {"bonus_summa": "200"},
                {"bonus_min_depozit": "1000000"},
                {"bonus_veizdjer": "4"}],
            "title": "Royal casino casino4"}}}
```

when I try loop

```
     for k,v in casino.iteritems():
         for iterm in v['fields']:
             print iterm['bonus_code']
```

`key:error`

what's wrong?

Comment: Is `casino` a dict with provided data?

Comment: @Aaron the issue is not that the key does not exist. OP just isn't getting far enough into the nested dictionary to access it.

Comment: You are not going deep enough, `for k, v in casino.iteritems():` will only iterate once, for the `16` key.

Comment: the very first item: ` "count_casinos": 4` will have no `['fields']`

Comment: also, the second loop will query each dict in the list separately, and only one of them has a `'bonus_code'` field, so all the others will generate a key index error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you iterate through `v['fields']` each item will be `dict` object with only one key, and only one item have `'bonus_code'` key.

Slight change that won't get you an error

```
 for k,v in casino.iteritems():
     for iterm in v['fields']:
         if 'bonus_code' in iterm: print iterm['bonus_code']
```

NOTE: if `casino` is initial_data dict `.get('casinos')`

**UPDATE**

I made a guess that OP's `casino` variable is

```
data = {"count_casinos": 4, "casinos": {"16": {"fields": [{"casino_logo": "assets/images/crown.png"}, {"raiting_casino": "9"}, {"bonus_code": "AX7772"}, {"bonus_summa": "200"}, {"bonus_min_depozit": "1000000"}, {"bonus_veizdjer": "4"}], "title": "Royal casino casino1"}, "17": {"fields": [{"casino_logo": "assets/images/crown.png"}, {"raiting_casino": "8.2"}, {"bonus_code": "AX777"}, {"bonus_summa": "200"}, {"bonus_min_depozit": "1000000"}, {"bonus_veizdjer": "4"}], "title": "Royal casino casino3"}, "18": {"fields": [{"casino_logo": "assets/images/crown.png"}, {"raiting_casino": "9.3"}, {"bonus_code": "AX7772"}, {"bonus_summa": "200"}, {"bonus_min_depozit": "1000000"}, {"bonus_veizdjer": "4"}], "title": "Royal casino casino2"}, "15": {"fields": [{"casino_logo": "assets/images/crown.png"}, {"raiting_casino": "9.9"}, {"bonus_code": "AX777"}, {"bonus_summa": "200"}, {"bonus_min_depozit": "1000000"}, {"bonus_veizdjer": "4"}], "title": "Royal casino casino4"}}}
casino = data.get('casinos')
```

because if `casino` would be initial `dict` that OP presented, then OP will get another error(`TypeError`), because values of `data['count_casinos']` is `int` and `int` don't have `__getitem__` method
which would raise `TypeError`.

Comment: Did you test this? `TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__' 
`

Comment: @roganjosh i added a note at the bottom of answer. Because `casino` is most likely value of initial data dict with key `'casinos'`, if it wasn't OP would get `TypeError` instead.

Comment: and what about other keys?

Comment: @VladleeleeLee you posted a code that raises an error, and the question was why you got. I answered it. The whole purpose of your program is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

You weren't going deep enough into the nested dictionaries. If you are only interested in the `casinos` section of data, something like this would work for you.

```
for k,v in casino['casinos'].iteritems():
    data_list = v.get('fields')

    # If you know the list index is consistent
    print data_list[2].get('bonus_code')

    #otherwise
    for item in data_list:
        if 'bonus_code' in item.keys():
            print item['bonus_code']
```

Comment: and what about others keys?

Comment: @VladleeleeLee I don't know what you're asking me. My code completes the task in your question; if you want to do something similar for other keys then you just need to make alterations to the structure of my answer to adapt it to your needs.